# How can I partition an array into specific sizes in php?

Tags: php, arrays, chunks

I have a set of numbers which define the sizes of each chunk. How would I go about chunking an array based on these sizes?

For example, suppose I have the chunk sizes *2*, *3* and *2*, and an input array of size 7:

```
array(
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'f',
    2 => 'j',
    3 => 'r',
    4 => 'c',
    5 => 'j',
    6 => 'd',
)
```

I would like the first *2* elements from the above array to chunked into their own array, the next *3* to be chunked into their own array, and the last *2* to be chunked into their own array. This would procude the following output:

```
// first 2 elements:
array(
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'f',
)

// next 3 elements:
array(
    0 => 'j',
    1 => 'r',
    2 => 'c',
)

// last 2 elements:
array(
    0 => 'j',
    1 => 'd',
)
```

My actual input array has 64 elements and I want to chunk it based on the sizes 7, 9, 11, 16, 9 and 12 in that exact order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function which partitions your array for you. You can first pass in the array, and then the chunks you require.

```
function partition($arr, ...$chunks) {
    $res = [];
    foreach($chunks as $n)
        $res[] = array_splice($arr, 0, $n);
    return $res;
}

$arr = ['a', 'f', 'j', 'r', 'c', 'j', 'd'];
print_r(partition($arr, 2, 3, 2));
```

The partitioning occurs by using [`array_splice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), which will change the array in-place. Each time `array_splice()` is called, you can grab the first `$n` elements from the array and push them into your result array. When you grab the first `$n` elements for a given chunk, you also remove them from the array.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => f
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => j
            [1] => r
            [2] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => j
            [1] => d
        )

)
```

See live example [here](https://3v4l.org/STiQ7)

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through your data.
- Keep current chunk count length in a variable.
- Keep decrementing count and add all looped elements to a temp array.
- If count reaches `0`, add the current chunk(as in temp array) to result and move on to the next chunk.
- Below code also works with irregular chunk size or data size.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$chunks_size = [7,9,11,16,9,12];
$data = ['a','f','j', 'r', 'c', 'j','d'];

$result = [];
$chunk_ptr = 0;
$count = $chunks_size[$chunk_ptr];
$temp = [];

foreach($data as $index => $val){
    $count--;
    $temp[] = $val;
    if($count == 0){
        $result[] = $temp;
        $temp = [];
        if(++$chunk_ptr == count($chunks_size)){
            $count = PHP_INT_MAX; // Set it to a higher value or any negative value(all remaining goes into the last chunk)
        }else{
            $count = $chunks_size[$chunk_ptr];   
        }
    }
}

if(count($temp) > 0) $result[] = $temp;


print_r($result);
```

**Note:** If `$chunks_size` is `0`, you can throw an exception as it doesn't make sense to loop through all elements.